# conditional construct not working in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a v-if statement wrapped around a template tag that shows up only when the type of signup is a referral. if the v-if evaluates to true, it displays a certain message within this template tag there are other nested v-if's.

Outside the above template tag, I have a v-else that should display a certain message if the type of signup is not a referral signup. The problem now is that the message for a referral and non referral signup display during a referral signup but a non-referral signup shows the correct message.

Below are the associate code.

```
            <template v-if="isReferralSignup">

                    <p v-if="canGetReferrerName" class="h4 pt-3 text-center">
                        Sign up to claim this investment from
                        <strong class="text-danger">
                            {{ReferrerFirstName}}
                        </strong>  and
                        get up to &#8358;{{RewardPerReferral}} in referral bonus
                    </p>
                    <p v-if="canGetReferrerName == false" class="h4 pt-3 text-center">
                        Sign up and get up to &#8358;{{RewardPerReferral}} referral bonus
                    </p>              
            </template>


            <p v-else class="h4 pt-3 text-center">
                You're opening a {{SelectedAccountName}} account
            </p>
```

Below is the func I'm using to check if it a referral or not

```
  isReferralSignup: function () {
                var self = this;
                var signUpUrl = document.location.href
                var splitUrlSegments = signUpUrl.split("/")
                var referralCode = splitUrlSegments[5]
                if (typeof referralCode === "undefined" || referralCode == ""  ) {
                    return false;
                } else if (referralCode.length == 6 || referralCode.length > 6) {
                    self.referralCode === referralCode
                    return true;
                }
            },
```

Please how do re-arrange my code to make it work as expected?

Thank you. PS: I'm using Vue.Js

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same tag for the `v-else`:

```
<template v-else>
   <p class="h4 pt-3 text-center">
      You're opening a {{SelectedAccountName}} account
   </p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to start the template tag for the v-else condition.

Try that:

```
<template v-else>
   <p class="h4 pt-3 text-center">
      You're opening a {{SelectedAccountName}} account
   </p>
</template>
```